# Incrementing array within parfor?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I am calculating sort of a histogram based on the distance between a pair of points in 3d space:

```
numBins = 20;
binWidth = 2.5;
pop = zeros(1,numBins);
parfor j=1:particles
    r1 = coords(j,:);
    for k=j+1:particles
        r2 = coords(k,:);
        d = norm(r1-r2);
        ind = ceil(d/binWidth);
        pop(ind) = pop(ind) + 1;
    end
end
```

This, expectedly, results in

```
Error: The variable pop in a parfor cannot be classified.
```

I understand the problem, but I am confused as to how can I solve it.
In principle, what could be done is to have `n` copies of `pop = zeroes(1,numBins)` be sent to each of `n` workers, and joined by adding each copy together at the end of computation. How can I do this here? Or is there another, more standard way of solving the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is two things that don't work in your code:

1) `for k = j+1:particles`

In a parfor a nested loop should have fixed bound.

2) `pop(ind)`

Matlab is afraid that the for-loop order matters and display an error message. Even if, in your **specific** case, the order doesn't matters (But matlab is not smart enough to know that).

The solution, Linearization:

```
%Dummy data
numBins = 20;
binWidth = 2.5;
particles = 10;
coords = rand(10,2)*40;

%Initialization
pop = zeros(1,numBins);

parfor j=1:particles
    r1  = coords(j,:)
    r2  = coords((j+1):end,:)          
    d   = sqrt(sum([r1-r2].^2,2)) % compute each norm at the same time !
    pop = pop + histcounts(ceil(d/binWidth),0:numBins) 
end
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Just a follow-up question: if I had a second array I was populating based on `d`, say `ind2`, would `ind` and `ind2` have the same order of elements?

Comment: Ok, nevermind, I guess you edited the code and my question is no longer relevant.

Comment: @sodiumnitrate I've edited my answer to correct a small mistake.

Comment: But to answer your second question. When you use parfor, the goal is to create, inside the parfor loop, a code where the order doesn't matters. But during one iteration of course `d` can be used several time to populate several variables

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function that computes the inner loop and use a handle to it in the parfor (I didn't tested it but I think it should work according to the documentation):

```
function pop = hist_comp(pop,j,particles,coords,binWidth)
  r1 = coords(j,:);
  for k=j+1:particles
      r2 = coords(k,:);
      d = norm(r1-r2);
      ind = ceil(d/binWidth);
      pop(ind) = pop(ind) + 1;
  end
end
```

```
numBins = 20;
binWidth = 2.5;
particles = 10;
coords = rand(10,2)*5;
pop = zeros(1,numBins);


f = @(pop,j) hist_comp(pop,j,particles,coords,binWidth);

parfor j=1:particles
  pop = f(pop,j);
end
```

Comment: Ho interesting, but I don't get why matlab is not displaying an error in this case ? Is that a way to trick matlab in order to force the execution of the parfor loop ?

Comment: It should not produce error. Here pop is a reduction variable. Each worker has a copy of pop. It is reduced to ...hist(hist(pop, n), n-1)